# open files when clicked in search results

Tags: unity, menu

When I click the unity start button, and type a file name and click a file among results, I get options to open file, open folder and email folder.

Is there a way to open files directly(without getting above option) on left click or enter ?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using, 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way - double click on the file instead of single-clicking it.

Comment: Not in GNOME :P :)